# Как вывести элементы массива, которые начинаются на букву A?

Tags: javascript

Проблема заключается в том что функция выводит тот же массив что и был изначально, а должна выводить массив с данными которые начинаются на А.

```js
const arrayThree = ['Andrew','Dmitriy','Maksim','German','Dasha','Anastasia'];
const letter = 'A';

function functionFiltersItems (elementArrayThree,letterElement) {
  return elementArrayThree.filter((letterElement) => letterElement.includes(letterElement));
}
console.log(functionFiltersItems(arrayThree,letter));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Похоже вот что вы хотели:

```js
const arrayThree = ['Andrew','Dmitriy','Maksim','German','Dasha','Anastasia'];
const letter = 'A';

function functionFiltersItems (elementArrayThree, expectedLetter) {
  return elementArrayThree.filter(letterElement =>
    letterElement
      .startsWith(expectedLetter)
  )
}

console.log(functionFiltersItems(arrayThree, letter));
```

Не самая лучшая практика использовать одинаковые имена для переменных и аргументов, можете запутаться, лучше для всего использовать разные имена, плюс к тому дебажить будет легче.

Comment: @NNL993 да я именно это имел ввиду. Я увидел в комментариях что вам не очень нравится конструкция: startsWith`A` в данном решение задачи. Если не сложно объясните почему.

Comment: @DmitriyYaroshchuk ну вообще, разницы работы нет никакой, но может быть проблема с компилябельностью, как я знаю трансляторы не переводят этот код в старый JS, в этом причина.

Comment: @NNL993 подскажите возможно ли в данном коде заменить startsWith на includes(), дабы избежать проблем в будущем.

Comment: @DmitriyYaroshchuk если хотите чтобы всё работало точно так как работает сейчас, то нет. `startsWith` проверяет на то, начинается ли строка введённый аргумент, а `includes` на, то есть ли в строке введённый аргумент.

Answer (score 4):

Вы должны передать функции `functionFiltersItems` только массив. Второй параметр отправлять не нужно.

Вот рабочий вариант.

```js
const arrayThree = ['Andrew','Dmitriy','Maksim','German','Dasha','Anastasia'];

function functionFiltersItems (elementArrayThree) {
  return elementArrayThree.filter((letterElement) => letterElement.toUpperCase().startsWith`A`);
}

console.log(functionFiltersItems(arrayThree));
```

Comment: Не совсем понимаю зачем вам такая конструкция: `startsWith\`A\``, если можно воспользоваться обычным методом обычным путём?

Comment: Похоже, что `letterElement` предполагался вторым аргументом и был предназначен для выбора самой буквы на которую будет идти проверка.

Comment: @ΝNL993 просто так захотелось написать. Для разнообразия. Чтобы ответ хоть чем то отличался от заурядного ответа на просторах интернета :)